# David Williams "Probability with martingales" theorem 3.2.b

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am having difficulty understanding the proof of that theorem:

First the  definition:

[image: definition]
then the theorem i am  having difficulty understanding the proof of:

[image: theorem 32b]

Now, I do understand that the class $\varepsilon$ exists in the first place because $C \subset \varepsilon$ by hypothesis, and yes, it is a sigma-algebra by (a). But what we want to prove is: for any element $A$ in the Borel sets, $h^{-1}(A) \in \Sigma$, so I am missing a step here ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathcal{E}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{C}$, so it contains the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}$ generated by $\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: yes, but how do we know this inclusion is not strict ?

Comment: By definition $\mathcal{E}$ is a class of elements in $\mathcal{B}$; on the other hand it contains $\mathcal{B}$ since it is a $\sigma$-algebra. So $\mathcal{E} = \mathcal{B}$.

Comment: Now it is very clear ! thank you so much !